# Запуск командной строки из gVim

Tags: cmd, vim

Как запустить командную строку (консоль) прямо из вима? 
Нашел следующий код для вывода результата работы питоновского скрипта в вим, хочется иметь возможность так же работать с тем же гитом, virt enviroment  и тд.

```
function! SaveAndExecutePython()
" SOURCE [reusable window]: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/autoload/go/ui.vim

" save and reload the current file
silent execute "update | edit"

" get file path of current file
let s:current_buffer_file_path = expand("%")

let s:output_buffer_name = "Python"
let s:output_buffer_filetype = "output"

" reuse existing buffer window if it exists otherwise create a new one
if !exists("s:buf_nr") || !bufexists(s:buf_nr)
    silent execute 'botright new ' . s:output_buffer_name
    let s:buf_nr = bufnr('%')
elseif bufwinnr(s:buf_nr) == -1
    silent execute 'botright new'
    silent execute s:buf_nr . 'buffer'
elseif bufwinnr(s:buf_nr) != bufwinnr('%')
    silent execute bufwinnr(s:buf_nr) . 'wincmd w'
endif

silent execute "setlocal filetype=" . s:output_buffer_filetype
setlocal bufhidden=delete
setlocal buftype=nofile
setlocal noswapfile
setlocal nobuflisted
setlocal winfixheight
setlocal cursorline " make it easy to distinguish
setlocal nonumber
setlocal norelativenumber
setlocal showbreak=""

" clear the buffer
setlocal noreadonly
setlocal modifiable
%delete _

" add the console output
silent execute ".!python " . shellescape(s:current_buffer_file_path, 1)

" resize window to content length
" Note: This is annoying because if you print a lot of lines then your code buffer is forced to a height of one line every time you run this function.
"       However without this line the buffer starts off as a default size and if you resize the buffer then it keeps that custom size after repeated runs of this function.
"       But if you close the output buffer then it returns to using the default size when its recreated
execute 'resize' . line('$')

" make the buffer non modifiable
setlocal readonly
setlocal nomodifiable
endfunction

" Bind F5 to save file if modified and execute python script in a buffer.
" Note: This is a normal mode bind because in insert mode F5 would insert a "<F5>" into the text.
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :<C-u>call SaveAndExecutePython()<CR>
```

Comment: Наберите `:!любая shell-команда`. Чем это не подходит? Для интеграции git есть множество плагинов, вот некоторые из них: [gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter), [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но к примеру, lein run (для clojure) не работает. Хочется из окна вима иметь доступ ко всем командам, доступным в командной строке, так как переключаться на cmd все время не удобно.

Comment: Виноват, работает, осталось только вывод оформить в окно вима, как в примере в моем вопросе. Буду пробовать.